# How to enable/disable <p:inputtext> depending on selecting values from<p:selectonemenu> dropdown in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

We are using JSF 2.2.4 and PrimeFaces 5 to develop some form fields.

For example: company and short code is my drop down and 'If you have selected Other' is my input-text field. So if user selects 'others' from the drop down the 'If you have selected Other' text field should be enabled, otherwise it should be disabled. 
Below is my code:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Company Name and Shortcode:* " escape="true" />

<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{user.shipper}" effect="fold" required="true" id="selectone" autocomplete="off" 
     requiredMessage="#{error['form.shippershortcode']}"  widgetVar="selectWV"  >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="----" itemDisabled="true"  />
        <f:selectItems value="#{shipperdropdown.shipperlist}"  />


</p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel  value="If selected ‘Other’ above, please specify:" 
                 escape="true"  />
               <p:inputText  value="#{user.companyname}" 
              autocomplete="off"  id="company"  disabled="#{ user.shipper !='Others'}"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this exact example:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

I think you just need to add in your p:selectOneMenu...

```
<p:ajax update="company" process="@this" />
```

So like this...

```
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{user.shipper}" effect="fold" required="true" id="selectone" autocomplete="off" 
     requiredMessage="#{error['form.shippershortcode']}"  widgetVar="selectWV"  >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="----" itemDisabled="true"  />
        <f:selectItems value="#{shipperdropdown.shipperlist}"  />
        <p:ajax update="company" process="@this" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: After using <f:ajax> the success messages is not getting displayed but in the background the code is running fine and i m getting desired output,but that output is not getting displayed in my front end

Comment: NOT f:ajax use "p:ajax" which is PrimeFaces version exactly like my example.

Comment: The field is getting disabled after using <p:ajax>,but when validation fails for other fields after submiting the form,the disabled field is getting back to enabled...please help regarding this

Comment: I beg you to study these examples on PF showcase:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml  Are you using disabled="" on your component?  You must be else a component would not go disabled.